# React component run error.Uncaught Error: Minified React error #31

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return some `html` label when write `render` in my component. Code like this:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Request from 'react-http-request';


class NameForm extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: '', result: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    var content = this.state.value;

    var split = content.split(/\s+/);

    var queryObject = new Object();

    queryObject.law = null;
    queryObject.character = null;
    queryObject.lawRule = null;
    if (split.length == 1) {
        queryObject.law = split[0];
    }
    else if (split.length == 2) {
        queryObject.law = split[0];
        queryObject.character = split[1];
    }
    else if (split.length > 2) {
        queryObject.law = split[0];
        queryObject.character = split[1];
        queryObject.lawRule = split[2];
    }
    // var json = JSON.stringify(queryObject);
    var json = "{\"law\":\"军工企业股份制改造实施暂行办法\",\"character\":\"第二章\"}";

    var test = JSON.stringify(<Fetchs args={json}/>);


    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/path', false);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var resp = '';
    request.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            resp = this.response;
        }
    }

    request.send(json);

    // console.info("XMLHttpRequest test is " + JSON.stringify(resp));

    // console.info("test is " + resp);

    this.setState({result: resp});

    event.preventDefault();
}


render() {

    // console.log("prite"+this.state.result.queryResults);
    // console.log("100"+this.strToJson(this.state.result));
    // console.log("200"+this.strToJson(this.state.result.queryResults));
    // alert(this.state.result);

    var parse = JSON.parse(this.state.result ? this.state.result : null);
    var out = parse ? parse.queryResults : null;
    for (var i = 0; out != null && i < out.length; i++) {
        if (out[i].keyword == null) {
            out[i].keyword = "{}";
            console.info("keyword is null");
        }
        else {
            // this.state.result.queryResults.keyword
            console.info("keword is not null");
            out[i].keyword = JSON.stringify(out[i].keyword);
        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
            <table border="10" >
                <tr>
                    <thead>
                    <th>GraphName</th>
                    <th>Relation</th>
                    <th>Content</th>
                    <th>KeyWord</th>
                    </thead>
                </tr>
                <tbody>

                {out}
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    );
 }
}


ReactDOM.render(<NameForm/>, document.getElementById('react'))
```

`out` is a array parsed from json data, like this:

[image]

My problem is that I want show `out` on page by `table` label, But use `{out}` I get a error, like this:
[image]

What troubled me is how to show `out` array in a table.

Comment: do what the error says and use the unminified version of react while you are developing. your error tells us almost nothing about what went wrong

Comment: you also need to wrap your table header row in a thead

Comment: last, table rows with the data not in a `td` is invalid html

Comment: I have updated my code, and still cannot show `out` data on page.

Comment: Could you show the part that you use to generate `{out}`?

Comment: I added generate part

Comment: The trouble thing is show each element in the array in the table. Can any advicees?

Comment: my advice is not to use a minified version of React until you're done bugfinding. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#development-and-production-versions

Comment: we're not here to write your code for you only to help you learn and solve problems. you need to help us help you by doing the leg work

Answer (score 12):

I believe your trouble maybe caused by the fact that you try to return array of objects in your react render method, instead try to map your objects and insert necessary fields in `<p></p>` tags.
For example:

```
out.map(
  (object) => <p>object.content</p>
)
```

etc...
Hope it helps!

Comment: by the way in this case you actually probably don't need to check if this is null or not better would be to return empty array from your server and when you will use map on empty array it will just display nnothing,i mean better check for nullness before setting state, so your render methot wont be polluted with conditional code

Answer (score 8):

**Future Readers!**

In my case I had incorrectly tried to output a string during the template iteration:

```
// Working
return <div>{list.map((name, i) => <div key={i}> {name} </div>}</div>
// Broken
return <div>{list.map((name, i) => <div key={i}> {{name}} </div>}</div>
//                                                ^ Incorrect (causes error #31)
```

Answer (score 3):

When i encountered this error, my first gaze of was that the difference themes and styling components i was using were conflicting. But latter own i discovered i was `rendering` wrong data format from my **database**.
The ***React Form field expected to receive a string*** but ***i was supplying an Object***

Answer (score 0):

When you do open with vs code on a folder then you create the react app in the terminal . It will generate a new folder on your actual folder make sure your terminal command is exceuted on the generated  react app folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[In my case:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP3wi.png)

```
html: <span>{reason}</span>
But the reason is object type => Error: Minified React error #31;
reason: {
  code: "other",
  id: 1,
  name: "Other",
  sub_reasons: []
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).